# What happened to Gillian from marketing in "USS Callister?"

Tags: black-mirror

In the first episode of Season Four of Black Mirror, "USS Callister," a CTO creates virtual "copies" of his coworkers inside his own private virtual world. Inside this virtual world, the characters allude to Gillian from marketing being turned into a arachnid monster because she crossed the character played by the CTO.

At the conclusion of the episode,

> the captive crew exploit a flaw and escape by killing themselves.

However, a well-emphasized limitation of this escape is that anyone who exists outside of the ship as it

> goes through the wormhole

will not escape.

So... what happened to characters like Gillian from marketing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gillian from marketing herself is probably fine and probably still working in marketing.

Unfortunately the copy of her remained in the CTO's unauthorized mod of Infinity until the core team flew through the "wormhole".  When this happened, the DRM system for Infinity recognized and deleted the game as it violated the EULA.  This system only recognized Gillian as an unauthorized mod and deleted her.  She simply ceased to exist.

The core team did not try to save her as they believed they would all just cease to exist as well.  The rather happy ending (all things considered) where the game deleted the CTO's mind and retained the core team as PCs or NPCs (not sure which) was a rather big surprise to them.